# Unity xcode "FBLPromises.h" file not found error

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a build from Unity Xcode project but getting this error.

[image]

I think that it might be related to `firebase` & `PromiseObjC` framework.
I don't know if is there any build setting that i am missing or overlooking.

It would be great if anyone has any idea about this

Thank you.